# Infinite complexes as functor categories.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I was thinking that if we have have an infinite complex in an abelian category $\mathscr{C}$ :

$...\xrightarrow{f_{i-1}} \mathcal{A}^i \xrightarrow{f_{i+i}}\mathcal{A_{i}}...$

Can be regarded as a functor from a small category $\mathscr{A}$ which has the form :

$...\Large{\cdot}$$\xrightarrow{g_i}\Large{\cdot}$$\xrightarrow{g_{i+1}}$$ \Large{\cdot} $$...$

But of course we must have $f_{i}\circ f_{i+1}=0$ so if we want to see the category of complexes on $\mathscr{C}$ as a functor category we should have a zero object in $\mathscr{A}$.

My question is what do you have to impose to $\mathcal{F} \in \mathscr{F}(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{C})$ in order to make sure that the imagen of $\mathscr{A}$ is a complex on $\mathscr{C}$? Is it necessary that the functor is additive?

Comment: Well you need to specify the composition of your category $\mathscr{A}$, don't you? What's $g_{i+1} \circ g_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define chain complexes as additive functors from the category enriched in abelian groups generated by your diagram with the relations $g_{i+1}\circ g_i=0$. Or, you could take the diagram you did and just impose the condition on $\mathcal F$ that...$f_{i+1}\circ f_i=0$, as usual.